# MySQL Multiple references between tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, enums

This question is probably quite easy to answer, but since I haven't got much experience in database design, I'm stuck. I don't even know how to google this because I don't know the terminology ....

I have a mysql database with two tables and in the first table i need to make MULTIPLE references to the second table. What should I use? Can I select multiple matches with Enum? Or should I just use a comma separated list and varchar?

```
|MAIN TABLE 
|==========================================
| id (primary index)
| date (tstamp)
| product name (varchar)
| componentids (int, enum, varchar ???)
|===========================================


|COMPONENTS TABLE
|===========================================
| componentid (int)
| name (varchar)
| info (varchar)
|===========================================
```

so a possible scenario would be this:

```
|MAIN TABLE 
|=====================================================
| id             | 1              | 2                |
| date           | 34958734958    | 349587123138     |    
| product name   | A test product | A second product |
| componentids   | 2,3            | 1,2              |
|=====================================================


|COMPONENTS TABLE
|========================================================
| componentid | 1           | 2           | 3           |
| name        | Component 1 | Component 2 | Component 1 |
| info        | info. text  | info. text  | info. text  |
|========================================================
```

how do I achieve this in an effective way?

thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is a many-to-many relationship. Each component can belong to multiple products, and each product can have multiple components. I'd strongly recommend using a third table for this, maybe called product_components.

Your main table has (id, date, name)
Your components table has (id, name, info)
Your product_components table has (product_id, component_id). Each of these is a foreign key that references the main table and component table respectively.

This maintains "referential integrity" which means that it becomes impossible to have a product referring to a component that doesn't exist (e.g. the database will throw an error if you try).

And yes, you can select the multiple components associated with one product in one go this way.

```
SELECT components.* 
FROM components 
JOIN product_components  
ON components.id = product_components.component_id
WHERE product_components.product_id = <some product id>
```

Comment: thank you! I think I got it. this means that in the example above, the product_components table would have the following entries?:

================
|prod_id|comp_id|
=====
|1|2|
|1|3|
|2|1|
|2|2|
=====

Answer (score 0):

No comma-separated lists or varchar.  That's not the relational way.

How should it go?  Are there many rows in the `main` table for every one in `component`, or visa versa?

A one-to-many relationship means adding a foreign key to the many table and JOINing the two:

```
select *
from main
join component
on main.componentid = component.componentid
```

This will match all the rows in the main table with their component counterpart.